# Fiz um código e não consigo identificar o erro. Sou novo na área da programação

Tags: javascript, html

O ''programa'' é esse:

```js
function verificar() {
  var país = document.getElementById('querochora')
  var res = document.getElementById('res')
  if (país != 'Brasil') {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você é estrangeiro.'
  } else {
    res.innerHTML = 'Você é <strong>Brasileiro</strong>.'
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>VERIFICADOR DE PAÍS.</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Digite abaixo o seu país.</h1>
  Seu país: <input type="text" name="país" id="país">
  <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick='verificar()'>
  <div id='res'>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Por algum motivo ele está errado, alguem consegue saber o porquê?

Comment: Teste assim `if (país.value != 'Brasil')`

Comment: tem que trocar o id do elemento no javascript por `país`. Pois o elemento com id `querochora`  não existe no seu html. Além de  fazer o ajuste do @AugustoVasques

Comment: Obrigado kkk
Vc pode me explicar o que significa esse (.value)?

Comment: Além disso tente explicar o problema, não só dizer que tem um erro, assim facilita a vida de quem está tentando ajudar.

Comment: E evite desde já usar acentos e caracteres especiais! Seja para nome de variáveis seja para nome de arquivos!!

Comment: O motivo de usar o `.value` é que `document.getElementById` te retorna um elemento do HTML, um input, no caso. O input tem uma propriedade chamada value, que é onde está o "valor" do input.

Comment: Diria ainda que a pergunta deveria ser fechada como "erro de digitação", uma vez que o problema é a troca do nome do elemento...

Comment: O .valeu vai pegar o valor do campo, no caso o seu campo é `pais` e ele vai pegar o valor deste campo (input).

Answer (score 1):

Olá, vamos lá:

Primeiro: o id que esta pegando no var pais = document.getElementById('querochora') no HTML não existe;

Segundo: caso troque o id de 'querochora' para 'pais' o pais.value pegará o valor digitado no input do html.

No caso ficaria assim seu if:

```
var país = document.getElementById('pais')
if (pais.value != 'Brasil') {
...
}
```

e seu html:

```
Seu país: <input type="text" name="país" id="país">
```

Outro ponto é que em um scenário perfeito o usuário digitaria o B do brasil maiusculo, sugiro que adicione um pais.value.toLowerCase() do JS para pegar o texto inserido pelo usuário em caixa baixa (famoso minusculo).

Veja a documentação da Mozila: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!